How to speak two sentence and join
I want mathematica to read two sentences and join these them together, how can I do that?
For example
a = "seternce a";
b = "seternce b";

The following attempts all failed
AudioJoin[Speak[a], Speak[b]];
AudioJoin[SpeechSynthesize[a], SpeechSynthesize[b]];

Speak returns Null, and SpeechSynthesize cannot be used in AudioJoin. It seems that the arguments of AudioJoin can only be "audio object", so how to generate a human voice "audio object"?

Remove the semi-colons. With v14 on a Mac, AudioJoin[Speak[a], Speak[b]] produces an error/warning message but speaks the two phrases. AudioJoin[SpeechSynthesize[a], SpeechSynthesize[b]] works without an error/warning message.

To join two sentences together and generate a single audio object in Mathematica, you can use the SpeechSynthesize function to convert the sentences to audio objects and then use AudioJoin to concatenate these audio objects. Here's how you can do it:
(* Define the sentences *)
a = "sentence a";
b = "sentence b";

(* Convert sentences to audio objects *)
audioA = SpeechSynthesize[a];
audioB = SpeechSynthesize[b];

(* Join the audio objects *)
joinedAudio = AudioJoin[{audioA, audioB}];

(* Play the joined audio *)
AudioPlay[joinedAudio]



Thank you very much.
